# RavenDb : LoadAsync with Include returns null

Tags: ravendb

I was adding some async calls in my project when i've encountered a problem. The same call between Session and AsyncSession doesn't return my document.

Here the document :

```cs
class Company {
    string Id;
    string Name;
    BusinessUnit BusinessUnit;
}

class BusinessUnit {
    string Name;
    List<BusinessUnit> BusinessUnits;
    List<Employee> Employees;
}

class Employee {
    string Position;
    string UserId;
}

class User {
    string Id;
    string FullName;
}
```

User and Company are two collections in my RavenDb. As you can see, we have a tree of business unit in our document Company. So when i want to load a Company, i make this call :

```cs
var company = Session.Include<Employee, User>(x => x.UserId)
    .Load<Company>(companyId); //Working like a charm
```

But when i tried to do the same with Async :

```cs
var company = await AsyncSession.Include<Employee, User>(x => x.UserId)
    .LoadAsync<Company>(companyId); //company is null

var company = await AsyncSession.LoadAsync<Company>(companyId); //This is working
```

I can't see why it isn't working.

During my searching of answers, i've found a small difference between the implementation of [MultiLoaderWithInclude](https://github.com/ravendb/ravendb/blob/f3b5f3a186d07776bf38bf9effab4d7d75d5c647/Raven.Client.Lightweight/Document/MultiLoaderWithInclude.cs) and [AsyncMultiLoaderWithInclude](https://github.com/ravendb/ravendb/blob/f3b5f3a186d07776bf38bf9effab4d7d75d5c647/Raven.Client.Lightweight/Document/AsyncMultiLoaderWithInclude.cs). I don't know if my issue can be resolved by these classes.

Comment: Can you submit a failing test to the mailing list? 
This _should_ work. Anything that is returned from Load should be returned from Load/Include.
See how to submit a failing test here:
http://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/3.5/Csharp/server/troubleshooting/sending-support-ticket

Comment: I've posted a failing test !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the failing test. The underlying reason is that you are using fields in there, not properties.
This is a bug in the client which will be fixed shortly, but in the meantime you can use properties and avoid it entirely.

Answer (score 0):

This won't load the related User documents in a single request.
You can do something like this:

```
var company = session.Include<Company, User>(x => x.BusinessUnit.Employees.Select(y => y.UserId)).Load<Company>(companyId);
```